# Serializing a TdwsProgram

Tags: delphi, dwscript

As I understand it, `DWScript` does not compile scripts into an intermediary bytecode. 
However, I would like to be able to store a "*compiled*" script, to be able to send it through a stream or save it to a file.

I was wondering: *Is there a way to serialize a `TdwsProgram` object?*

I didn't manage to find any answer anywhere. I have looked over the code and it doesn't seem to be possible, but I thought I should ask the question anyway...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I remember, it is not implemented nor wanted by its actual maintainer (since the execution AST is a tree of objects).

See this reference article about [Why no bytecode format](http://delphitools.info/2010/10/26/why-no-bytecode-format/).

The easiest would be to first stream the source code, then compile it again.

*DWS compilation is very fast, faster than Delphi, and Eric tries to always improve it, even if new features are added.*